# Fast Load 50k rows from csv or pandas to Amazon Aurora (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

**Kindly note answers need to work in an AWS Lambda - as such this is not a generic MySQL question.**

I have a pandas dataframe in AWS Lambda. It contains 50k rows and I need to load this into Amazon Aurora (MySQL).

Using `df.to_sql (even with method='multi')` is woefully slow.

The best way to do it would be to save a .csv, and then use the superfast MYSQL     `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command.

I save the df to a csv in lambdas \tmp\foo.csv but then `con.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...")` Doesn't work.

I get an SQL error

> Access denied for user...

I log in to the db as root, but can't grant. The MySQL flag is set to local-infile=1.

So, in summary: How can I FAST load 50K rows from a csv to MySQL Aurora db in AWS Lambda?

**Discounted Solution**

One solution I've already discounted is to export the csv to a S3 bucket, and then use the Amazon's  "LOAD DATA FROM S3". This seems terribly inefficient (not to mention all that S3 transfer/storage cost).

Comment: FYI there's no cost to put data into S3 and no cost to retrieve data from S3 to EC2 or Lambda in the same region. How did you get the 50k rows in the first place? Perhaps your upstream process should just put that data directly into S3, then trigger the load to Aurora.

Comment: Hi - I read the large (>100k rows) csv into pandas via s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(key, '/tmp/foo.csv') then pd.read_csv which is fast. I then preprocess the dataframe in lamba and finally want to export to Amazon Aurora (MySQL flavour).  That's the problem; using pd.to_sql is crazy slow, per question.